# How to show Membership Roles in the Gridview as Columns Dynamically

Tags: asp.net, gridview, asp.net-membership

I am Using Membership to define roles in Asp.net.Now as per my requirement i need to show the      Roles as dynamic Columns of gridview with first two columns as fixed and rest of the columns as per the number of Roles in table but i have no idea of how to meet that as i have never worked on it before..

Here is my static gridview code in aspx page...

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow" BorderColor="Tan"
                    BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="2" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="None" 
                    Width="477px">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkhdr" runat="server" />
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkChild" runat="server" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Username">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("col0") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Role(Admin)">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAdmin" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("col1") %>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Role(DPAO User )">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkUser" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("col2") %>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Role(GeneralUser)">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkgen" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("col3") %>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>   
                </asp:GridView>
```

And here is the code to load grid with data...

```
protected void BindGridviewData()
{

    var role = from MembershipUser u in Membership.GetAllUsers()
               select new
               {
                   User = u.UserName,
                   Role = string.Join(",", Roles.GetRolesForUser(u.UserName))
               };


    DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
    dTable.Columns.Add("col0", typeof(string));
    dTable.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(bool));
    dTable.Columns.Add("col2", typeof(bool));
    dTable.Columns.Add("col3", typeof(bool));
    foreach (MembershipUser u in Membership.GetAllUsers())
    {
        DataRow dRow = dTable.NewRow();
        dRow[0] = u.UserName;

        string[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(u.UserName);
        dRow[1] = roles.Contains("Admin") ? true : false;
        dRow[2] = roles.Contains("DPAO User") ? true : false;
        dRow[3] = roles.Contains("GeneralUser") ? true : false;
        dTable.Rows.Add(dRow);
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = dTable;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

In the given Grid I need first two columns as fixed and other column based on value from the Role table from membership...

Any help will be highly appreciated.Thanks in advance..

Comment: Am assuming your datatable's column `col0,col1` would be fixed and other column will generate dynamically, so create databale as its generate column dynamically and add it to your datatable, later bind datatable with gridview and in gridview allow **`AutoGenerateColumns=true`**

Comment: @Satindersingh yes sir col0,col1 will be fixed

Comment: you can add column like `// Method 1 
    dt.Columns.Add ("column0", System.Type.GetType ("System.String")); 
    // Method 2 
    DataColumn dc = new DataColumn ("column1", System.Type.GetType ("System.Boolean")); 
    dt.Columns.Add (dc);`

Comment: @Satindersingh Sir here we are assigning column by ourself but my requirement is to iterate to the number of Roles came from Role table and generate column for those ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **dynamically Show** , **Update roles** and **Delete records** try this:

ASPX:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound1"/></asp:GridView>
<asp:Button ID="cmdDelete" runat="server" onclick="cmdDelete_Click1" Text="Delete" />
<asp:Button ID="cmdUpdateRole" runat="server" onclick="cmdUpdateRole_Click" Text="Update Roles" />
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGridviewData();
    }       
}
protected void BindGridviewData()
{
    DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
    dTable.Columns.Add("Select", typeof(bool));
    dTable.Columns.Add("Username", typeof(string));
    dTable.Columns.Add("Role(Admin)", typeof(bool));
    dTable.Columns.Add("Role(DPAO User)", typeof(bool));
    dTable.Columns.Add("Role(GeneralUser)", typeof(bool));
    foreach (MembershipUser u in Membership.GetAllUsers())
    {
        DataRow dRow = dTable.NewRow();
        dRow[0] = false;
        dRow[1] = u.UserName;
        string[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(u.UserName);
        dRow[2] = roles.Contains("Admin") ? true : false;
        dRow[3] = roles.Contains("DPAO User") ? true : false;
        dRow[4] = roles.Contains("GeneralUser") ? true : false;
        dTable.Rows.Add(dRow);
    }
    GridView1.DataSource = dTable;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}   
protected void cmdUpdateRole_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        string username = row.Cells[1].Text;
        CheckBox chkAdmin = (CheckBox)row.Cells[2].Controls[0];
        CheckBox chkUser = (CheckBox)row.Cells[3].Controls[0];
        CheckBox chkgen = (CheckBox)row.Cells[4].Controls[0];         
        List<string> roles=new List<string>();   
        if (chkAdmin.Checked)
            roles.Add("Admin");
        if (chkUser.Checked)
            roles.Add("DPAO User");
        if (chkgen.Checked)
            roles.Add("GeneralUser");
        if (Roles.GetRolesForUser(username).Length > 0)
        {
            Roles.RemoveUserFromRoles(username, Roles.GetRolesForUser(username));
        }
        if (roles.Count > 0)
        {
            Roles.AddUserToRoles(username, roles.ToArray());
        }
        BindGridviewData();
    }
}
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound1(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        CheckBox c0 = (CheckBox)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
        CheckBox c2 = (CheckBox)e.Row.Cells[2].Controls[0];
        CheckBox c3 = (CheckBox)e.Row.Cells[3].Controls[0];
        CheckBox c4 = (CheckBox)e.Row.Cells[4].Controls[0];
       c0.Enabled=c2.Enabled =c3.Enabled=c4.Enabled= true;
    }
}
protected void cmdDelete_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
        if (chk.Checked)
        {
            string username = row.Cells[1].Text;
            Membership.DeleteUser(username);
            BindGridviewData();
        }
    }
}
```